# Dealing with comments to the site's community

Tags: discussion, comments

I came across this question on M.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718131/create-formula-to-solve-for-s

After 14 minutes of no responses,(pretty normal since there is no work provided) the OP decided to post a comment about the community:

> That's ok. StackExchange and the people who dwell on it are useless anyway. #worthlesswebsite. Mathematics people who refuse to help with algebra. Temp account is temporary. Trash web site.

My question is, how to deal with this type of comments?

Comment: Point and laugh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag it as "not constructive".  Or, if you think it crosses a line, "rude".

Under some circumstances, enough flags from the community can auto-delete a comment.  For the rest, the mods will see the flags and they can delete.